# auto-delete menu entries as part of a bash script

Tags: bash

I want to delete menu commands that are in the form of -

```
[exec] (foobar) {/usr/lib/xscreensaver/foobar -root}
```

and there are 50+ commands to be deleted as part of a bash-script. But, how do I do it please? I need some form of commands that I can put into my menu generation script, which will auto-delete them in the future.

Comment: This question is unclear. For what I guess you can use: `sed -e '/^\[exec\]/d' -i file-with menu`. If that's not the result you want to achieve, please describe your problem in more precise way.

Comment: This is one line of a fluxbox menu, and there are 50+ lines like it. They serve no purpose so I wish to delete them at the time the menu is generated, but the menu is regenerated with every new programme installed, so they will need to be deleted once again. So I need a command that can be added to the autogeneration script that will delete them again. As these are menu items, they are in a file called 'menu'. The menu lines to be deleted will always contain {/usr/lib/xscreensaver/ *** -root}, so that could be used as the identifier. Does this help?

Comment: Still, I don't know, what is the common part of lines you want to delete. Try to tune the regular expression - replace `^\[exec\]` with pattern common to unwanted lines. However, knowing the problem, it would be better if you find the source files responsible for generating those entries and remove it. I do not know what distribution you are using, but you can start in /usr/share/menu.

Comment: I'm using debian testing with fluxbox as my DE. The common identifier is  {/usr/lib/xscreensaver/ *** -root}, and the menu can be generated by, in this case 'menumaker', or 'fluxbox-generate_menu', and I don't have the skills or knowledge to work in those files. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works -

```
sed -i '\|\[exec[]]\s[(].*[)]\s[{]/usr/lib/xscreensaver/.*\s-root[}]|d' ~/.fluxbox/menu; sed -i '\|\[exec[]]\s[(].*[)]\s[{]\b\(xscreensaver\).*[}]|d' ~/.fluxbox/menu
```

Watch out for line wrapping, it is all one line. But, is there a better way?

Comment: You can think about shortening the expression a little. Maybe just /xscreensaver/ will be sufficient pattern. You can check what would be deleted with: `sed -n '/pattern/p' file`. And if you run `sed '/pattern/d' file`, without `-i` option, you will see what your file would look like.